# wordpress - Add custom param after postname

Tags: wordpress, routes, url-parameters

I'm using Wordpress permalink with this structure

```
domain/%postname%/
```

I want to add a custom param after postname, something like this

```
domain/%postname%/%custom_var%/
```

This I want it to show post content and I can access custom_var in code. It means the system will work the same for

```
domain/postname
```

and

```
domain/postname/custom_var
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307713/add-a-permalink-variable-onto-custom-post-type-url-after-post-name-slug

Comment: Thanks, I did try that solution before. However it will create a url like this:  

domain/mycpt/postname/custom_var

instead of 
domain/postname/custom_var

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat possible and not possible,

First you cannot get a URL structure like `domain/postname/custom_var` and play with its rewrite rule, the rewrite rule for this is use by wordpress default URL structure and messing with it could cause a lot of problems
.e.g

```
domain/category/cat-1 - for category
domain/taxonomy/tax-1 - for taxonomy
domain/archive/2022 - for archive
and so on.....
```

If you dump the `WP_Rewrite` Object, you'll see under the `rules` property this has already been handled `[[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]` and the url with structure `domain/sub-1/sub-2/` will do `index.php?attachment=$matches[1]` request

On the other hand, you could add a rewrite tag e.g.

```
add_rewrite_tag('%custom_var%', '([^/]+)', 'custom_var=');
```

then use that tag on your post permalink `/%postname%/%custom_var%/`

but this set-up would break your first goal and this URL structure `domain/postname` would no longer work.

However, there's another option you can do, and that is to add a pre-fix on your 2nd level path and add rewrite rule matching that url structure prefix,

Here's a whole example

create a rewrite rule that matches `domain/***/s-***/` and set a custom query

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)?/s-([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pname=$matches[1]&custom_var=$matches[2]','top');
});
```

(you need flush your rewrite rule after adding that code above, simply go to permalinks, switch it plain, then swtich it back to postname) or just run this function `flush_rewrite_rules()` you can then dump `$wp_rewrite` global variable and verify your rule is their

and set those query on wordpress query vars so you can simply access them

```
add_filter( 'query_vars',  function( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = 'pname';
  $vars[] = 'custom_var';
  return $vars;
});
```

Now the exciting part; modify the global `$post` and `$wp_query` variable when query var `pname` exist.

Something like this would do

```
add_action( 'wp', function() {

  global $wp, $wp_query, $post; //define global variable
  //include $wp variable so you can check the url request

  // check if pname var is set
  if (  isset( $wp_query->query['pname'] ) ) {

      // build query argument
      $args = [
          'page' => '', //assuming its a page
          'pagename' => $wp_query->query['pname']
      ];

      // run the query and assign it to $wp_query global variable
      $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

      // modify is_single wp_query param and tell it its not a post
      $wp_query->is_single = '';


      // modify is_page wp_query param and tell it its a page
      $wp_query->is_page = 1;

      //assign  (1st) found post to global post variable
      $post = $wp_query->posts[0];
      //done
  }

  // Test Dump
  //echo '<pre>', print_r($wp_query, 1), '</pre>';
  //echo '<pre>', print_r($wp_rewrite, 1), '</pre>';
  //echo '<pre>', print_r($wp, 1), '</pre>';
});
```

So if you try to access.

`domain/page-1/s-test`

it should display the page as long as `page-1` is a post object

Comment: Thanks a lot Silver. I've followed your instruction and it works.